# How to use fmap on [maybe string] so added string is before Just?

Tags: haskell, option-type

I got following function:

```
maybeStrings:: [Maybe String] -> [Maybe String]
maybeStrings s = fmap ("Hello, "++) <$> s
```

The question is, how can I get that "Hello, " before Just?
For example, user gives following list: `[Just "Simpson"]` and the output currently is `[Just "Hello, Simpson"]`. I want it to be: `["Hello, Just Simpson"]`.

Comment: You need to perform a double `fmap`.

Comment: You can not get `"Hello"` before the `Just`, since the result is a `Maybe String`, and `"Hello"` is just a `String`. Since a list can only contain one type of elements, you can not store both `String`s and `Maybe String`s in the list.

Comment: What should `maybeStrings [Nothing]` produce?

Comment: If list has Nothing, then it produces Nothing.

Comment: So `maybeStrings [Nothing] = [Nothing]`?

Comment: Yes that is right.

Comment: And `maybeStrings [Just Simpson, Nothing] = ...`?

Comment: `maybeStrings [Just Simpson, Nothing] = ["Hello, Just Simpson", Nothing]`

Comment: @JonHarper As @willemvanonsem has pointed out, `["Hello, Just Simpson", Nothing]` is not well-typed. You can't have a `String` and a `Maybe String` value in the same list. You *could* return `[Just "Hello, Just Simpson", Nothing]`, though.

Comment: I think you need to describe in more detail what the actual logic is that you desire for this function.

Comment: What you ask cannot be done. So now you must say why you want to do that thing, so that we may suggest alternatives that get you where you need to go without doing this exact thing that you ask to do.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the simpler function

```
foo :: String -> String
foo x = "Hello, Just " ++ x
```

Then use `fmap` *twice*: once to map `foo` over a `Maybe` value, and again to map your `fmap`ped function over a list of `Maybe` values:

```
> fmap foo Nothing
Nothing
> fmap foo (Just "Simpson")
Just "Hello, Just Simpson"
> fmap (fmap foo) [Just "Simpson", Nothing]
[Just "Hello, Just Simpson", Nothing]
```

Then

```
maybeStrings :: [Maybe String] -> [Maybe String]
maybeStrings = fmap (fmap ("Hello, Just " ++))
```

Comment: I wanted to emphasize what each step produces, in part to explain why you can't get a list with both a `Maybe String` and a `String` in it.

Answer (score 0):

> I want it to be: `["Hello, Just Simpson"]`

I assume that this is a typo, and that you want:

```
["Hello", Just "Simpson"]
```

This is however not possible. A list contains elements that are all of the *same* type. But here your list would contain a `String` and a `Maybe String`, which does not make much sense.

If you want to prepend the list with `Just "Hello"`, you can use operator sectioning here:

```
maybeStrings :: [Maybe String] -> [Maybe String]
maybeStrings s = (Just "Hello" :)
```

If you want to convert the `Just x` to a string `"Hello, Just` , you can use a mapping like:

```
maybeStrings :: [Maybe String] -> [String]
maybeStrings = map f
    where f (Just x) = "Hello, "  x
          f Nothing = _
```

but then you need to return a string for the `Nothing` part. You can not store both `String`s and `Maybe String`s in the list.

Another sensical candidate, advised by [@dopamane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59826845/how-to-use-fmap-on-maybe-string-so-added-string-is-before-just/59826923#comment105796565_59826923) is using [**`catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes). This takes a list of `Maybe`s and takes the `Just`s to convert it to a list of items. We thus can define a function:

```
import Data.Maybe(catMaybes)

maybeStrings :: [Maybe String] -> [String]
maybeStrings = map ("Hello, " ++) . catMaybes
```

Comment: So it's not possible to insert Just Simpson after hello String? I want `["Hello, Just Simpson"]`

Comment: @JonHarper: but `"Just Simpson"` is *not* a string. It is a `Just` data constructor that wraps a `"Simpson"` string. You can, as specified, only have a `Maybe String` in this list.

Comment: Using `catMaybes` from [Data.Maybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes), `maybeStrings = map ("Hello, Just " ++) . catMaybes`. Then you can ignore the Nothing case.

Comment: @dopamane: yes, that looks like a sensical candidate as well. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result to be `["Hello, Just Simpson"]`, try this:

```hs
formatMaybeString :: Maybe String -> String
formatMaybeString Nothing = "Nothing"
formatMaybeString (Just x) = "Just " ++ x

maybeStrings :: [Maybe String] -> [String]
maybeStrings s = fmap (\maybeString -> "Hello, " ++ formatMaybeString maybeString) s
```

Notice that I changed the type signature of `maybeStrings` from your `[Maybe String] -> [Maybe String]` to my `[Maybe String] -> [String]`. This is because `["Hello, Just Simpson"]` isn't a list of `Maybe String`s, it's a list of ordinary `String`s. You won't be able to keep the original type signature and return a list with values like `"Hello, Just Simpson"`.